# Question about using WPF’s animation and TranslateTransform3D

Tags: c#, wpf, 3d

In this WPF C# project one goal is to animate movement of an object from one location to another in the 3D space. The Transform property of the GeometryModel is set to a TranslateTransform3D object instance and its OffsetX, OffsetY, and OffsetZ are set - to animate the object to its new location.

When the animation happens it seems to animate each of OffsetX, OffsetY, and OffsetZ separately. That creates a visual stair-step effect as the object repositions. Is there a way to maybe animate along a vector between the old and new positions to achieve a smoother visual effect?

I've read lots on various forums that WPF does indeed animate first X then Y then Z. Might anyone know a way combine the animation steps perhaps along a vector or something?

Here is a C# snippet of current attempt:

```
using System;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Animation;
using System.Windows.Media.Media3D;

namespace SimWPF2
{
    public class Object
    {
        #region Properties
        public GeometryModel3D ObjectModel { get; set; }
        private Point3D CurrLocation = new(), NewLocation = new(); // Universe coords
        private TranslateTransform3D TranslateTransform3D { get; } = new();
        #endregion

        public Object()
        {

            CurrLocation.X = CurrLocation.Y = CurrLocation.Z = 0D;

            // Reticle model
            MeshGeometry3D SphereMesh = new();
            Sphere.AddSphere(SphereMesh, CurrLocation, .5D, 10, 10);
            ObjectModel = new()
            {
                Geometry = SphereMesh,
                Material = new DiffuseMaterial(new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Red)),
                Transform = TranslateTransform3D
            };
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Position object to new location
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="camera"></param>
        /// <param name="newLocation"></param>
        public void Position(SimCamera camera, Point3D newLocation)
        {
            // Reposition object
            //
            // **************************
            // This causes WPF to animate and reposition the object. But it animates X, then Y, then Z
            // giving the animation a stairstep effect as it moves on the screen.
            // Is there a way to maybe animate along a vector between the old and new positions to achieve a smoother visual effect?
            // **************************
            //
            newLocation = newLocation;
            TranslateTransform3D.OffsetX = NewLocation.X;
            TranslateTransform3D.OffsetY = NewLocation.Y;
            TranslateTransform3D.OffsetZ = NewLocation.Z;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You need to show us the code of your animation.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

WPF’s built-in Animation support will, as far as I can see, not support animation of a GeometryModel along a vector from one location to another. No worries though. As this is using frame-based animation via

```
CompositionTarget.Rendering
```

It is a straight-forward matter to translate/animate the GeometryModel from one position to another along any vector during frame rendering. Basically not using WPF’s builtin animation support.